# How to get docker-compose restart with the latest version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pull

So I've been into a problem, I have a docker-compose.yml file with

```
- restart: always
```

But when it restart it doesn't pull before, is there a way to do it without creating an external service ?

Comment: Restaring doesn't pull new containers. You can run `docker-compose pull` first to just download the new container. Then follow up with `docker-compose up -d` and it will recreate any service that has a new image. The other ones will just stay up since they are already up-to-date.

Comment: If you know a specific image tag you want to use, changing the Compose `image:` to point to the new tag and running `docker-compose up -d` will do what you need.  This will delete and recreate any containers with updated images or other changed configuration, and leave the rest alone.  This approach doesn't use the restart policy at all.